# JSON data into CSV using Groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, groovy-eclipse

```json
    {
        "BRANCH": "master",
        "name": "customer",
        "product_name" : "PQ",
        "domain" : "Shopping",
        "_id": "12345"
    }
```

Given a JSON file containing JSON data to convert into CSV/Excel using Groovy code. Anyone, please help me. I have to convert JSON data into CSV/Excel using Groovy code.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: How do you expect to deal with attributes that are objects?  For example `{ "myAttr": { "name":"steve" } }`

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

JSON is best represented as a map structure, and it is hard to represent a map as a csv.  However based off the sample JSON you provide you could use something similar to the following

```
def jsonSlurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
def json = jsonSlurper.parseText('{"BRANCH": "master","name": "customer","product_name" : "PQ","domain" : "Shopping","_id": "12345", "asdf":["asdf","asdf"], "obj":{"a":"b", "c":"d"}}')

def result = json.collect { new StringBuilder().append('"').append(it.value).append('"') }.flatten().join(",")

println result
```

The above code would also work for attributes that are arrays and objects, but entire array/object would be one cell in the CSV file.

[image: output]